# SQL query returns only 1 row and what is the correct way to join more than three tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, fiddle

I'm working on this hotel reservation system.

I have multiple table for customer, reservation, bill, rooms, room type, agency.

I'm making a receipt.

All these tables are connected but I'm only getting a single row of information instead of three information of receipt.

I'm just a beginner so bear with me if my query is not that complex or experienced enough.

BTW I'm using sqlfiddle.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT r.bill_ID
     , c.name
     , b.payment_type
     , b.card_number
     , a.agency_name
     , mt.description
     , SUM(x.fee) Amenities
     , mt.room_rate Room
  FROM reservation r
  JOIN bill b
    ON b.bill_ID = r.bill_ID
  JOIN agency a
    ON a.agency_ID = r.agency_ID
  JOIN room m 
    ON m.room_ID = r.room_ID
  JOIN amenities x 
    ON b.amenity_ID = x.amenity_ID
  JOIN customer c
    ON c.cust_ID = r.cust_ID
  JOIN roomType mt
    ON mt.type_ID = m.type_ID;
```

Here is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE roomType(
  type_ID varchar(15) PRIMARY KEY,
  description varchar(45),
  room_rate int);
                      
CREATE TABLE amenities(
  amenity_ID varchar(15) PRIMARY KEY,
  amenity_name varchar(45),
  fee decimal(4,1));
  
CREATE TABLE agency(
  agency_ID varchar(15) PRIMARY KEY,
  agency_name varchar(45));
  
CREATE TABLE customer(
  cust_ID varchar(15) PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar(45),
  address varchar(45),
  contact_no varchar(45),
  email varchar(45),
  agency_ID varchar(15),
  FOREIGN KEY (agency_ID) REFERENCES agency(agency_ID));
  
CREATE TABLE bill(
  bill_ID varchar(15) PRIMARY KEY,
  cust_ID varchar(15),
  amenity_ID varchar(15),
  agency_ID varchar(15),
  payment_type varchar(5),
  card_number int,
  amount int,
  FOREIGN KEY (agency_ID) REFERENCES agency(agency_ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (amenity_ID) REFERENCES amenities(amenity_ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (cust_ID) REFERENCES customer(cust_ID));
  
CREATE TABLE room(
  room_ID varchar(15) PRIMARY KEY,
  type_ID varchar(15),
  room_num int,
  max_guest int,
  availability varchar(15),
  FOREIGN KEY (type_ID) REFERENCES roomType(type_ID));
  
CREATE TABLE reservation(
  rsrvtn_ID varchar(15) PRIMARY KEY,
  bill_ID varchar(15),
  cust_ID varchar(15),
  room_ID varchar(15),
  agency_ID varchar(15),
  check_in date,
  check_out date,
  num_guest int,
  book_status varchar(10),
  FOREIGN KEY (agency_ID) REFERENCES agency(agency_ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (bill_ID) REFERENCES bill(bill_ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (cust_ID) REFERENCES customer(cust_ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (room_ID) REFERENCES room(room_ID));
  
CREATE TABLE administrator(
  admin_ID varchar(15) PRIMARY KEY,
  admin_lvl varchar(15),
  rsrvtn_ID varchar(15),
  bill_ID varchar(15),
  room_ID varchar(15),
  cust_ID varchar(15),
  FOREIGN KEY (cust_ID) REFERENCES customer(cust_ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (rsrvtn_ID) REFERENCES reservation(rsrvtn_ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (bill_ID) REFERENCES bill(bill_ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (room_ID) REFERENCES room(room_ID));
```

Comment: Which sqlfiddle dbms are you using? The JOIN's look fine, but the SUM() make you need a GROUP BY at the end. Or use a window function.

Comment: Make it easy, and possible, to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: I'm using MySQL 5.6

Comment: There's no evidence of a fiddle here.

Comment: MySQL 5.6, I'd say use a correlated subquery to calculate SUM().

Comment: Sorry I've used the ``` wrongly and the first line of query doesn't show up. Thanks for the edit

Comment: You need to show table schemas, example data, desired output, current output, and an explanation of the difference/problem between them.

Comment: I did put a GROUP BY in the query and I'm getting a result of 3 rows of information having the same data of a person instead of showing the other 2 information of people

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query has a `SUM()` which makes it an aggregation query.  An aggregation query with no `GROUP BY` returns exactly one row.  Or an error.

Your query should be returning an error.  Why?  The `SELECT` columns are not consistent with the `GROUP BY` column.  All the unaggregated columns should be in the `GROUP BY`:

```
GROUP BY r.bill_ID, c.name, b.payment_type, b.card_number, 
         a.agency_name, mt.description, mt.room_rate
```

This is common-sense.  It is required by most databases.  And it is even what is current versions of MySQL support.

Unfortunately, once-upon-a-time, MySQL supported the syntax in your question.  Since MySQL 8.0, this is no longer the default behavior.  It is controlled by a system setting `only_full_group_by`, which is explained in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html).